# svn - create new branch from uncommitted code base

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

So here is what I would like to do:

Check out a untracked copy of the code framework using something like this

```
svn export http://svnrepo/project/framework/tags/1.0.2/ . --force
```

now I would like to create a new branch in another repo but how?

Do I use `svn import`, `svn add`?

So this is where I would like to store it:

```
svn ci http://svnrepo/newproject/branches/new_feature/
```

Suggestions?

Solution:

this works for me

Initial Checkout without svn history

```
svn export http://svnrepo/project/framework/tags/1.0.2/ . --force
```

Create the branches directory

```
svn mkdir http://svnrepo/newproject/branches/new_feature/
```

Checkout empty branch

```
svn co http://svnrepo/newproject/branches/new_feature/ .
```

Add exported project

```
svn add *
```

Check in export into new branch

```
svn commit -m "export to new branch committed"
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this via the command line or are using a gui like Tortoise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export is mistake - you can't commit not from WC, Working Copy is result of checkout.

You *may* have UUID-trouble on commit, but you can at least to try

```
svn co OLD-URL
svn mkdir NEW-URL 
svn relocate NEW-URL
svn ci
```

**Version with history-lost**

```
svn export OLD-URL WC1
svn mkdir NEW-URL
svn co NEW-URL WC2
```

copy files from WC1 to (empty) WC2

```
cd WC2
svn add
svn ci
```

Comment: Does this still work if I don't want the history of the export?

Comment: @PhillPafford - my 1-st way *save history*

Comment: Thanks! Added the solution to my question. One small change is I don't have to change directories